# Python - append zeros to beginning of numbers depending on the string length

Tags: python, append, string-length

i have python script that results in numbers, for example

1001

10001

100001

i need to append zeroes at the beginning that the length is always equal to 10

0000001001

0000010001

0000100001

i need to know how to do it in python

thanks in advance

Comment: Use string formatting `f"{num:010}"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out an answer :

```
x = 1001

n = 10-len(x)

zeros = '0'*n
```

and then i can append the zeros to x value and wrap it in a str

Answer (score 0):

In python, numbers with leading 0’s will raise an error. You can, however, format them in when displaying them as a string, which is what @ddejohn mentioned in the comments.

Comment: ok i can wrap it in a str , however i don't know how to asign the number of zeros
lets say i want to make Z or X 
i tried n = 10-len(1001) that gave me the n of zeros i have to assign m but i don't know how to use this n to add the digits i needed

Comment: `"0" * n + "the rest of the num"` should work.